# Nested animation block caused "Segmentation fault"

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-animation, xcode4.2, block

I try to show three images, one after one, with the following code:

```
image_1.alpha = 0.0;
image_2.alpha = 0.0;
image_3.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                 animations:^{
                     image_1.alpha = 1.0;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                                      animations:^{
                                          image_2.alpha = 1.0;
                                      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                                                           animations:^{
                                                               image_3.alpha = 1.0;
                                                           } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                                               ;
                                                           }];
                                      }];
                 }];
```

gives: `internal compiler error: Segmentation fault`

There is no error if the nesting contains two animation blocks. Is nested animation block no allowed or comes with some limitation?

Comment: So it crashes when you compile it (and not when you run it)?

Comment: I was curious so I've tried the exact code in a new project and it works for me without any problems with both gcc 4.2 and lvvm 1.5.

Comment: @Codo no crash, just a compilation error.

Comment: I am also getting a sig fault: 11 if I nest enumerateObjectsUsingBlock beyond 2 levels. To get around this for now I've switch back to a classic for..loop in the 3rd nesting.